# Make inner divs not exceed the boundary of the outer div, CSS, HTML

Tags: html, css

I have 4 divs. Three divs are inside of another one. I need it so that no matter how much pixels of width or height the divs have on the inside, they'll never exceed the boundary of 100px width, and 100px height of the div on the outside. Is there a way to do this in css?

```
<style>

#outside {
background-color: green;
position: absolute;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
}
#inside {
background-color: red;
position: absolute;
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
}

</style>


<div id = 'outside'>

<div id = 'inside'></div>
<div id = 'inside'></div>
<div id = 'inside'></div>

</div>
```

Comment: Please provide a jsFiddle of what you have thus far.

Comment: IDs **must** be unique.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

something like this is what you're looking for if you want to adjust the inside div dimensions to the outside div dimensions.

```css
#outside {
  background-color: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
.inside {
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 48%;
  height: 48%;
}
```

```html
<div id = 'outside'>

    <img class="inside" src ="http://hasslefreeliving.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/placeholder.gif" />
    <img class="inside" src ="http://hasslefreeliving.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/placeholder.gif" />
    <img class="inside" src ="http://hasslefreeliving.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/placeholder.gif" />

</div>
<br/>
this is the normal image size<br/>
<img src ="http://hasslefreeliving.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/placeholder.gif" />
```

Comment: Close. But I need 3 pictures.

Comment: That fit on the inside.

Comment: Otherwise, instead I could just set the width and height of the picture to 100px width and height, instead of putting it inside a div with the height and width of 100px.

Comment: @frosty, or if that isnt a satisfactory solution, would you be able to give me the dimensions of these three inner divs compared to the 100px by 100px? like what you want the resulting three divs to look like?

Comment: Nevermind. I got what I was looking for. I just had to make the innner divs relative, so their percentage is relative to the outside before I can move it around inside the div. Otherwise, if I set the width of the inner div to 50% with position absolute, it'll adjust it to 50% of the body of the page. Which makes it really big. lol. thanks.

Answer (score 6):

depends what you want to happen, if you want the inner divs to be just abruptly cut off, you can use `overflow:hidden;` on the `outside` div

or if you want the inner div to never be wider than the outer div use `max-width:100%;`.  But by looking at your `200px` value for your inner div, it looks like you want them to be bigger, but just no show all of the inner div.

http://jsfiddle.net/cL1rvr4u/

Comment: What does overflow:hidden; mean?

Comment: it means... anything that is going to overflow that div, hide it.

Comment: I need it to auto-adjust all the divs on the inside so they all can be seen, without exceeding the limit of 100px width, and 100px height.

Comment: @frosty pretty much means that if elements that are placed in the `#outside div` would normally leak out (go beyond the `100px` by `100px` bounds), the leakage will be hidden from view

Comment: if the inner divs need to be the same width as the outer - `width:100%;`.  If they can be no wider than the outer div - `max-width:100%;`

Comment: @indubitablee That would mean that if there are words inside those divs, they would also be hidden from view. I need it so that it actually shows everything, without exceeding the limit.

Comment: @andymccullough That would mean that if there are words inside those divs, they would also be hidden from view. I need it so that it actually shows everything, without exceeding the limit.

Comment: @frosty, ahh i see, wasnt clear in your original post that you wanted to adjust the size of the inner divs. take a look at my example for the adjust solution

Answer (score 0):

try adding`overflow:hidden;` to the `#outside` div.

Comment: I need it to auto-adjust all the divs on the inside so they all can be seen, without exceeding the limit of 100px width, and 100px height.

Comment: try `width:100%` and `max-width:100%` on the inside divs

Comment: It won't work because then only one of the divs are going to be shown, and there are 3 of them.

Comment: then try `float:left` on the inside divs instead of `position:absolute`. if you position absolute they will stack on top of on of another. you also need the `max-width:100%;` property on the inside divs

Answer (score 0):

**I would do this:**  [position:relative;](http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/relative-positioning/)

```
#outside {
background-color: green;
position: relative; // change outter div to relative so child is relative to
max-width: 400px; // add a max-width to determine max-width
height: 100px;
}
#inside {
background-color: red;
position: absolute;
width: 100%; // change to 100% if you want to be 100% of above or parent
height: 200px;
overflow:hidden; // might as well add this too
}
```

Comment: I need it to auto-adjust all the divs on the inside so they all can be seen, without exceeding the limit of 100px width, and 100px height.